# EuropassCV: How to replace ugly "europass"-logo with some custom text?

Tags: cv, europasscv

For international applications I use [this europasscv](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/europasscv?lang=en)-template.

However, many personell managers do not like Europass-templates because they are looking extremely corny and kitschy (what I can understand). Therefore I want to replace this ugly "europass"-logo with some custom text.

Depending on the description of the [manual](http://ftp.math.purdue.edu/mirrors/ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/europasscv/europasscv.pdf#subsubsection.3.1.1) it seems to be easy to remove the logo with a simple `\documentclass[nologo]{europasscv}`. However, how is it possible to place some custom text at the previous logo position (e.g. "EUROPEAN CURRICULUM VITAE FORMAT") to make it look a bit more professional?

---

**I would desire some nice text header like that:**

[image]

---

**Minimum Working Example (MWE):**

```
\documentclass[english,a4paper]{europasscv}%            optional: nologo
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\ecvname{Katie Smith}
\ecvaddress{12 Strawberry Hill, Dublin 8 Éire/Ireland}
\ecvmobile{+353 555 123 555}
\ecvtelephone{+353 127 6689}
\ecvworkphone{+353 999 888 777}
\ecvemail{smith@kotmail.com another@email.com}
\ecvhomepage{www.myhomepage.com www.another-homepage.com}
% \ecvgithubpage{www.github.com/smith}
% \ecvlinkedinpage{www.linkedin.com/in/katie-smith}
\ecvim{AOL Messenger}{katie.smith}
\ecvim{Google Talk}{ksmith}

\ecvdateofbirth{1 March 1975}
\ecvnationality{Irish}
\ecvgender{Female}

% \ecvpicture[width=3.8cm]{picture.jpg}

% \date{}

\begin{document}
  \begin{europasscv}

  \ecvpersonalinfo

  \ecvbigitem{Job applied for}{European project manager}

  \end{europasscv}

\end{document}
```

Comment: \documentclass[english,a4paper, nologo]{europasscv}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing in the code to allow to replace this. So you would have to replace the pdf logo of the pdf or to copy the page style definitions and change them. You can adapt the \parbox to your need (e.g. move it up and down with \raisebox) but the width should be the same as the graphic.

```
\documentclass[english,a4paper]{europasscv}%            optional: nologo
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
\fancypagestyle{ecvfancy}{
\setlength{\headheight}{13.5pt}
% \setlength{\footskip}{8.4pt}
\fancyhead{}

\fancyhead[R]{
\raggedleft \selectecvfont \textcolor{ecvhighlightcolor}{\ecv@name}
}

\fancyhead[L]{
  \setlength{\difflength}{\ecv@leftcolwidth}
  \addtolength{\difflength}{-0.6\ecv@logowidth}
  \noindent
  \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    \noindent\makebox[\ecv@leftcolwidth][l]{\noindent\raisebox{-6.5pt}[0pt][0pt]{\if@ecvlogo
    %\includegraphics[width=0.6\ecv@logowidth]{europasslogo2013.pdf}
    \parbox[b]{0.6\ecv@logowidth}{some text second page\\ some text}%
    \else \hspace{0.6\ecv@logowidth}\fi}\hspace{\difflength}\hspace{\ecv@colsep}{\ifx\@empty\ecv@notitle \empty \else \ecvcoloredtitle \fi}}
  \end{minipage}
  }
}

\fancypagestyle{first}{
\fancyhead[R]{}
\fancyhead[L]{
  \setlength{\difflength}{\ecv@leftcolwidth}
  \addtolength{\difflength}{-\ecv@logowidth}
  \noindent
  \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    \noindent\makebox[\ecv@leftcolwidth][l]{\noindent\raisebox{-10.5pt}[0pt][0pt]{\if@ecvlogo%
    %\includegraphics[width=\ecv@logowidth]{europasslogo2013.pdf}
    \parbox[b]{0.6\ecv@logowidth}{some text title page \\ some text2}%
    \else \hspace{\ecv@logowidth}\fi}\hspace{\difflength}\hspace{\ecv@colsep}{\ifx\@empty\ecv@notitle \empty \else \ecvcoloredtitle \fi}}
  \end{minipage}
  }
}
\pagestyle{ecvfancy}}
\makeatother

\ecvname{Katie Smith}
\ecvaddress{12 Strawberry Hill, Dublin 8 Éire/Ireland}
\ecvmobile{+353 555 123 555}
\ecvtelephone{+353 127 6689}
\ecvworkphone{+353 999 888 777}
\ecvemail{smith@kotmail.com another@email.com}
\ecvhomepage{www.myhomepage.com www.another-homepage.com}
% \ecvgithubpage{www.github.com/smith}
% \ecvlinkedinpage{www.linkedin.com/in/katie-smith}
\ecvim{AOL Messenger}{katie.smith}
\ecvim{Google Talk}{ksmith}

\ecvdateofbirth{1 March 1975}
\ecvnationality{Irish}
\ecvgender{Female}

% \ecvpicture[width=3.8cm]{picture.jpg}

% \date{}

\begin{document}
  \begin{europasscv}

  \ecvpersonalinfo

  \ecvbigitem{Job applied for}{European project manager}
 \newpage 

  \ecvbigitem{Job applied for}{European project manager}

  \end{europasscv}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your great help! Unfortunately I receive an error with the following line: `\fancyhead[R]{
   \raggedleft \selectecvfont \textcolor{\ecvhighlightcolor}{\ecv@name}}` This error disappears if I remove the part `\selectecvfont \textcolor{\ecvhighlightcolor}`... What could it be? The logfile says: `! Undefined control sequence.
\f@ncyorh -> \raggedleft \selectecvfont 
                                        \textcolor {\ecvhighlightcolor }{\ec...
l.77 \end{document}`

Answer (score 1):

Download [europasslogo2013.pdf](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/europasscv?lang=en) edit it with GIMP for example (maintain original height and width). Place it just near your main.tex

[image]

Comment: Haha, this would be too easy... :-)

Comment: it worked for me https://www.overleaf.com/read/ncrbnbrsjbhp

Answer (score 1):

Simply change the Logo width & offset to 0 cm in `eurpasscv.cls`

Update in `europasscv.cls` Line 610 and 611 to (Under the comment Logo Size)

```
% Logo size
\ecvLogoWidth{0.0cm}
\ecvLogoOffset{0.0cm}%\typeout{logo width=\the\ecv@logowidth}
%\typeout{logo offset=\the\ecv@logooffset}
```

Comment: Please, can you add a complete MWE to see the output?

Comment: I think you missunderstood the question. The question is to have **instead the image** an special text printed in the CV, and not -- as you showed in your answer -- only deleting the logo ... BTW: Changing the `*.cls` file is not a good idea (copyright and other issues), better is to add redefinitions or patches in the preamble of your own CV ...

Answer (score 1):

There is an option for the document class for removing the europass logo. Please refer to the [europasscv package documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/europasscv) (chapter: *Class options/Appearance options*).

Just add "nologo" option to the *documentclass* command. It would be something like:

```
\documentclass[english,a4paper,nologo]{europasscv}
```

and you can also remove the title:

```
\documentclass[english,a4paper,nologo,notitle]{europasscv}
```

The overall result:

[image]